# Converting Paperclip to Carrierwave | undefined method `exists?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

I'm converting my app from paperclip to carrierwave based on the documentation on carrierwave's github:https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave and advice from this blog:http://bessey.io/blog/2013/04/07/migrating-from-paperclip-to-carrierwave/

However I'm getting a undefined method error for `exists?' in Articles#show.

**Here is my _form.html.erb code**

```
 <%= form_for(@article, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>
       .
       .
       . 
        <p>
            <% if @article.image.exists? %>
                <%= image_tag @article.image.url %><br />
            <% end %>
            <%= f.label :image, "Attach a New Image" %><br />
            <%= f.file_field :image %>
         </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.submit %>
        </p>
        <% end %>
```

**Here is Articles#show**

```
def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end
```

**The Articles Model**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader, :mount_on => :image
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    has_many :comments
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
    # has_attached_file :image
    # validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]

    def total_pages
        @articles = Article.all
    end

    def tag_list
        self.tags.collect do |tag|
            tag.name
        end.join(", ")
    end

    def tag_list=(tags_string)
        tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
        new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
        self.tags = new_or_found_tags
    end
end
```

Let me know if you need to see anything else. I'm still learning rails and I'm not sure where I need to be looking to debug this particular error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the presence of the image you can just use

```
<% if @article.image_url %>
     <%= image_tag @article.image.url %><br />
<% end %>
```

For more information about setting up carrier wave in your app check this episode of [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. And thanks for the railscast reference.